# How do I pass dns parameters during boot

Tags: boot, kernel, dns, debian

Now,

I boot a berryboot installation and I can pass an ipv4=192.168.1.xx/255.255.255.0/192.168.1.x parameter to set the networking. However, I haven't found a way to pass a dns parameter of say 8.8.8.8 during the boot in the cmdline.txt.

p.s. - I know this sounds like a pi question but I feel like this is a debian/ubuntu kernel question.

Comment: An obvious question would be... why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 5):

In diskless booting (e.g. using NFS), you often specify ip4 as follows:

`ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>`

Perhaps that's the syntax you were looking for and would work in your instance?

Here's the kernel doc reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt